# Displacement on Cubes

Tags: displacement

Trying to get displacement working on a cube. I found that particularly the edges are receiving a good amount of bump/ displacement vs. the top face of the platform/ cube. I have subdivided the cube plenty.  Is there any other advice someone can give that maybe I might have overlooked.

Again, samples below, no issue on a flat plane surface, but on a cube it seems to not be adjusting too well. Is there a way I can distribute more displacement on the top, can it be done by weight painting perhaps?

[image]

[image]

This is the result on top of the cube closeup:
[image]

Comment: Any particular reason this has to be a cube?  Have you tried adaptive subdivision?  I notice you're set to experimental.

Comment: The way this cube is scaled the side vertices are probably much closer together, making the displacement effect more pronounced.

Comment: Thanks Allen, I will make sure adaptive sampling is turned on. And yes it was off, it's fixed now.